# standardization of all variables LASSO/OLS

Tags: data-preprocessing, lasso-regression, standardization

i am running two regressions on the same variables (lasso and ols regression).
should i standardize all variables X (including the independent variable y)?
when standardizing features/regressors and the output variable, the mean squared error is a lot smaller than when only standardizing dependent variables (and not standardizing the independent variable)